# `\includeonly` and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, include

Following the method described [in the LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents), I have set up the folders of my project in the following fashion:

```
Project...  
  main.tex  
  mystyle.tex
  img...
    fig1.png
  tex...
    frontmatter...
      awknowledgements.tex
    mainmatter...
      intro.tex        
      conclusion.tex
    backmatter...
      biblio.bib
```

I can easily compile the complete document using `\include`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\author{Erika Mustermann}
\title{My BIG Project}

\frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \include{./tex/frontmatter/awknowledgements} 
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter
    \include{./tex/mainmatter/intro}
    \include{./tex/mainmatter/conclusion}

\backmatter
    \clearpage
    \bibliography{./tex/backmatter/biblio/}

\end{document}
```

This works without any problem. However, if I try to compile a limited number of chapters using the following `\includeonly`, I get errors and the document doesn't compile:

```
...
\includeonly{./tex/mainmatter/intro}
...
```

> Database file #1: ./tex/backmatter/biblio.bib (There were 3 error
>   messages)
>
> Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" did
>   not succeed.

The error messages are namely:

> intro.tex Package natbib Warning: Citation `Mustermann_2016' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.
>   main.tex Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
>   main.tex LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

(There is only 1 citation in `intro.tex`.)

I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong or missing. I read that it might have something to do with being unable to find the .aux file, but I'm not sure if there's a way to solve it. I moved my bibliography file into the top project folder where the `main.tex` is saved, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I also saved **everything** into the top-level folder and the issue was not resolved. Perhaps it is in the way that I make the bibliography? Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated!

**Edit** Using `\includeonly` works fine when the bibliography is commented out which is what led me to believe the issue is there.

Comment: FWIW: `\bibliography{./tex/backmatter/biblio/}` looks wrong, why the final slash?